# Login Issue for Google Play Services using Unity Android

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to integrate Google Play game Services in unity for android platform.. And I have integrated and configured in google play developer console. And I have red all the forums and tried all the possibilities that our friends suggest but still When I am pressing login button nothing happens in android mobile..

Please some body help me solve this problem..

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty vague question, so here is a general answer:

First, check out the QuickStart for [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart).  This covers the general concepts.  Pay special attention to how to configure your game in the developer console; this is where most of the problems first time developers with GPGS have issues.

Next, download the Unity plugin from GitHub:
 https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

This repository also has instructions on how to configure the plug in within the Unity environment.

After that, run the samples provided with the plugin, these are applications that are known to work and demonstrate how to call the plugin.

Finally, integrate the plugin into your own game and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find application "Google Settings" in your mobile.
open "connected apps" and select your app here.
at bottom there will be a button "Disconnect",after these steps than try to login.
Or tell step by step how you are doing ?